# How to include an internal android layout?

Tags: android, layout, view, android-preferences

Android has some built-in layouts. For example: `com.android.internal.R.layout.preference`

I want to create a new layout that contains above internal layout, then add some views below it. I know I can use `include` tag. But what exactly I have to write inside `include` tag to point it to `com.android.internal.R.layout.preference`?

Comment: Did you try something so far ?

Answer (score 0):

use `include` tag to include other layouts in your xml.

But there is special Activity and Fragment for app preferences. [Here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html) you can read more about them.

Comment: I know that I can use `include` tag. But what should I write inside `include` tag to point it to the `com.android.internal.R.layout.preference` layout?

Comment: You can't include internal layouts in xml. Use PreferencesFrament or PreferencesActivity instead